# Linking Paypal account with Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

In my project, I want to link the paypal account to my railsapp. so that whenever the user makes payment, he should login to paypal to do so. how to accomplish this?

Comment: Use gem omniauth-PayPal

Answer (score 2):

here is the link for gem [omniauth-paypal](https://github.com/datariot/omniauth-paypal).

How to integrate paypal in rails application, refer below links:

[integrate login with paypal](http://cristianobetta.com/blog/2013/09/27/integrating-login-with-paypal-into-rails/)

[basic-paypal-integration-in-rails](http://deepakrip007.wordpress.com/2013/10/02/basic-paypal-integration-in-rails/)